# If a graph is k-connected, does it mean it has at least one group of k separators?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

This question is about clarifying some terms. I am trying to make sure that I understand them correctly.

If a graph is k-connected, then the removal of < k vertices keeps the graph connected. Thus, if removing some k vertices disconnects it, do we call these k vertices a separator?

If I am correct, then a graph can have several separators but all of them must have the same size = k. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question in your title; yes.  If a graph is $k$-connected then it must have at least one group of k-separators.  This is why complete graphs are excluded when defining $k$-connectivity on the basis of the smallest subset of vertices that can disconnect the graph when removed; because complete graphs have no separators.

Your intuition is correct and I would only modify your last statement to be precise:

A $k$-connected graph can have several *minimal* separators, each of which must be of size $k$.  You can also have non-minimal separators of size $> k$.